# how do i convert javascript new Date() method to fa-IR

Tags: javascript

hey guys I got a similar code from the w3school website and i need convert date to fa-IR
like this new Date("شهریور 5, 1400 15:37:25")
please help me thanks

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Where would the converted date be shown? You want `42 روز 22 ساعت 46 دقیقه 14 ثانیه` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```js
const options = {
    day: "2-digit", month: "long", year: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric", minute : "numeric", second : "numeric"
};


// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;


  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fa-IR',options).format(new Date())

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "تمام شده";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **toLocaleDateString();**

```
let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('fa-IR');
console.log(today);
```

or

```
const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.info(d.toLocaleDateString("fa-IR", options))
// output> ۱۰ خرداد ۱۳۹۹
```